# How to show message bar on every page

Tags: asp.net, notification-bar

I work with ASP.NET VS2005.  In stackoverflow, every now and then, a message bar is displayed at the top of the page. When clicked on the message's hyperlink, it takes me to another page which has all information regarding to the context of the message bar.  How do/could I do that?

When bar comes up, it shows on all of the open pages.

I want to show a bar dynamically.  In my system, I have 10 users, suppose one user want to save something, I want it to show to all other users after saving. How do/could I do that?

Comment: `in stackoverflow several time show popup message` What do you mean by pop-up in SO? Is it like the one when you type an answer and then navigate away from the page? Other then that, I don't recall any other pop-up.

Comment: When you say "popup" I take it you mean the bar at the top that says something like: "You have 2 new responses.  View your profile".?

Comment: @scunliffe: That's what I thought too. Is that called a 'pop-up'? To me, it's a notification prompt :P

Comment: Ah, ok, it's the `message bar` after the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some asked on SO:
[Stackoverflow Style Notifications in asp.net Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465/stackoverflow-style-notifications-in-asp-net-ajax)
[Web usability: alert/notification - how to attract attention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505471/web-usability-alert-notification-how-to-attract-attention)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or reverse-AJAX. Google will give you more answers now that you know what to look for ;)